# How to list Category - Subcategory in navigation menu in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How to list Category - Subcategory in the navigation menu in Laravel?

I have a query like this below.

```
id  Title    parent_id
1   cat1     1
2   cat2     1
3   cat3     2
4   cat4     3
```

Answer (score 0):

add these functions to your model

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)

   @if($category->parent_id == 0)

      @include('categories.view', $category)

    @endif
@endforeach
```

And the is content of **categories.view.blade** file

```
<li id="{{$category->id}}" data-jstree='{"icon":"fa {{$category->icon}}"}'>

  <a href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>

  @if ($category->children()->count() > 0)
    <ul>
      @foreach($category->children as $category)
         @include('categories.view', $category)
     @endforeach
   </ul>
  @endif
</li>
```